# How to search through each letter in a dictionary and use it properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv, dictionary

If I were to take a dictionary, such as

```
living_beings= {"Reptile":"Snake","mammal":"whale", "Other":"bird"}
```

and wished to search for individual characters (such as "a")                (e.g.

```
for i in living_beings:
    if "a" in living_beings:
        print("a is here")
```

would there be an efficient- runs fastest- method of doing this?

The input is simply searching as outlined above (although my approach didn't work).

My (failed) code goes as follows:

```
animals=[]
for row in reader: #'reader' is simply what was in the dictionary
    animals.append(row) #I tried to turn it into a list to sort it that way
for i in range(1, len(animals)):
    r= animals[i] 
    for i in r:
        if i== "a": #My attempt to find "a". This is obviously False as i= one of the strings in 
            k=i.replace("'","/") #this is my attempt at the further bit, for a bit of context
            test= animals.append(k)
            print(test)
```

In case you were wondering,
The next step would be to insert a character- "/"- before that letter (in this case "a"), although this is a slightly different problem and so not linked with my question and is simply there to give a greater understanding of the problem.

**EDIT** 
I have found another error relating to dictionary. If the dictionary features an apostrophe (') the output is affected as it prints that particular word in quotes ("") rather that the normal apostrophes. EXAMPLE:  `living_beings= {"Reptile":"Snake's","mammal":"whale", "Other":"bird"}` and if you use the following code (which I need to):

```
new= []
for i in living_beings:
    r=living_beings[i]
    new.append(r)
```

then the output is `"snake's", 'whale', 'bird'` (Note the difference between the first and other outputs). So My question is: *How to stop the apostrophes affecting output*.

Comment: Please provide an example of expected output to be clear.

Comment: Are you trying to search the keys or the values?

Comment: as a side note, you should never use `for i in range(1, len(animals))` instead of `for i in animals`. In fact, you should _almost never_ use `range()`.

Comment: @DYZ, why? What's wrong with it?

Comment: @DYZ why? b/c you get the wrong indexes as 1-off? is using `for (idx, item) in enumerate(l):` better to get an index?

Comment: @Someone Because you never really need `i` in you code, except for fetching the `i`th list item - and you can do it directly without generating the unnecessary index variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach would be to use dict comprehension to map over the dictionary and replace every occurence of `'a'` by `'/a'`.

I don't think there are significant performance improvements that can be done from there. You algorithm will be linear with regard to the total number of characters in the keys and items of the `dict` as you need to traverse the whole dictionary whatever the input.

```
living_beings= {"Reptile":"Snake","mammal":"whale", "Other":"bird"}
new_dict = { 
    kind.replace('a', '/a'): animal.replace('a', '/a') for kind, animal in living_beings.items()
}
# new_dict: {"Reptile":"Sn/ake","m/amm/al":"wh/ale", "Other":"bird"}
```

You could *maybe* optimize with a more convoluted solution that loops through the `dict` to mutate it instead of creating a new one, but in general I recommend not trying to do such things in Python. Just write good code, with good practices, and let Python do the optimization under the hood. After all this is what [the Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) tells us: *Simple is better than complex*.

Comment: I don't get how this would improve the efficiency at all. We still need to search in linear time.

Comment: It is probably the most straightforward way to do it in Python. It is linear, but you have to go through the whole dictionary so you cannot avoid that. If we need an increase in efficiency by a constant, I'd recommend switching language.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done quite efficiently using a regular expression match, e.g.:

```
import re
re_containsA = re.compile(r'.*a.*')
for key, word in worddict.items():
    if re_containsA.match(word):
        print(key)
```

The re.match object can then be used to find the location of the matched text.

Comment: I think you should do `re.compile(r'a')` and use `re.findall` instead of `re.match` to find all occurences.